# In Angular, how do I expose a variable from a parent component to a child component?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a component in which the user of this component can embed its own contents and access the variable the parent is exposing.

Say I have the following parent component template

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'parent',
      template: `<ng-container>
                  <ng-content [select]="content"></ng-content>
                </ng-container>`
    )}
```

Here is an example of how the component will be used.

```html
    <parent>
      <div content>
        <button (click)="x.close()"></button>
      </div>
    </parent>
```

I need to have `x` variable exposed to the user of the component. How do I do this in Angular?

The reason I want to do this is because the parent must not know anything about the child component it is going to contain that's why I thought of just exposing a variable. In this way, only child needs to be aware about the parent but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a variable from the parent component you can use Template variable reference(`#`) in html. Please refer below.

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'parent',
      template: `<ng-container>
                  <ng-content [select]="content"></ng-content>
                </ng-container>`
    )}
    export class ParentConteinr {
      x = {
         close: () => { // code to close }
      }
    }
```

```html
    <parent #parent>
      <div content>
        <button (click)="parent.x.close()"></button>
      </div>
    </parent>
```

Comment: That worked! Is this somewhere to be found in official Angular documentation?

Comment: Yes, It is available in angular docs. [Refer here](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)